# Laravel : How do I add key and value into Collection or array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I get a collection from Database and I can use toarray() changing the type but I don't how to add key and value into collection or array

this is my collection

```
Collection {#225 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#222 ▼
      +"product_id": 48
      +"product_name": "xxxxxxx"
      +"product_number": 400
      +"product_price": 300
      +"product_describe": "qqqqqqqqqq"
      +"product_status_id": 1
      +"product_category_id": 1
      +"product_buy_price": 200
      +"created_at": null
      +"updated_at": null
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my array

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#222 ▼
    +"product_id": 48
    +"product_name": "xxxxxxx"
    +"product_number": 400
    +"product_price": 300
    +"product_describe": "qqqqqqqqqq"
    +"product_status_id": 1
    +"product_category_id": 1
    +"product_buy_price": 200
    +"created_at": null
    +"updated_at": null
  }
]
```

I  want to add into array key and value.

```
"buynumber" => "$buynumber"
```

I try to use merge. 
Controller.php

```
        $buynumber = Input::get('buynumber');
        $product_id = Input::get('product_id');
        $product = DB::table('product')
                        ->where('product_id', $product_id)
                        ->get();

        $product_array = $product->toArray();
        $buy_number = array('buynumber' => $buynumber);
        $merge = array_merge($product_array, $buy_number);
        return  View('shop/cart')
                    ->with('merge',$merge);
```

It's not I want.

merge result

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#222 ▼
    +"product_id": 48
    +"product_name": "xxxxxxx"
    +"product_number": 400
    +"product_price": 300
    +"product_describe": "qqqqqqqqqq"
    +"product_status_id": 1
    +"product_category_id": 1
    +"product_buy_price": 200
    +"created_at": null
    +"updated_at": null
  }
  "buynumber" => "5"
]
```

How can I get one array not two array?

Comment: You can try ```$product_array = $product->first()->toArray();```

Comment: From a quick look if `$product` always return one product you may use `->first` instead of `->get` and  rest should work

Comment: I hope so. @RanjanaLK

Comment: I use $product_array = $product->first()->toArray(); 
and I got error "Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()"

Comment: @Daniel0909 Because you are using `DB::talbe()`, it return `stdClass`, it has no `toArray()` method. If you want to use `first()->toarray()`, you need to use Eloquent.

Comment: However, if you use `first()`, Only display one product, you need to use one loop instead of two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `$product` variable always returns one row (if `product_id` is the primary key or a unique column then this is the case) you can use `->first()` instead of `->get()` as `->first()` only returns an object where `->get()` return a collection.

If you use `->first()` you should get a result set like this

```
{#222 ▼
  +"product_id": 48
  +"product_name": "xxxxxxx"
  +"product_number": 400
  +"product_price": 300
  +"product_describe": "qqqqqqqqqq"
  +"product_status_id": 1
  +"product_category_id": 1
  +"product_buy_price": 200
  +"created_at": null
  +"updated_at": null
}
```

then you can cast `$product` object to an array like this `$product_array = (array)$product;` and you would get an array like below

```
array[
  "product_id"=> 48
  "product_name"=> "xxxxxxx"
  "product_number"=> 400
  "product_price"=> 300
  "product_describe"=> "qqqqqqqqqq"
  "product_status_id"=> 1
  "product_category_id"=> 1
  "product_buy_price"=> 200
  "created_at"=> null
  "updated_at"=> null
]
```

then you can add whatever the elements you want to it

```
$buy_number = array('buynumber' => $buynumber);
$merge = array_merge($product_array, $buy_number);
```

or you can simply do

```
$product_array['buynumber'] = $buynumber;
```

which will get you a result like this

```
array[
  "product_id"=> 48
  "product_name"=> "xxxxxxx"
  "product_number"=> 400
  "product_price"=> 300
  "product_describe"=> "qqqqqqqqqq"
  "product_status_id"=> 1
  "product_category_id"=> 1
  "product_buy_price"=> 200
  "created_at"=> null
  "updated_at"=> null
  "buynumber"=>"whatever the buy number you passed here"
]
```

If your `$product` variable return multiple results then you can't use `->first()`. Then you may loop through the `$product_array` and cast each element to an array and then add necessary elements

Comment: Could I ask that if I want echo $product_array in view page.which command I can use? I use  it but I got error "Trying to get property of non-object".
foreach ($product_array as $item)
        {{ $item->product_id }}
        {{ $item->product_name }}
        {{ $item->product_number }}    
        {{ $item->buynumber }}
    endforeach

Comment: Its probably happening because you're trying to access an array like an object, try like this instead `{{ $item['product_id'] }}`. Since you're new to Stackoverflow I'm providing an answer which is not related to original question in comments. Please ask a new question if it's not directly related to original question and also search for questions which were already answered here in SO.

Answer (score 2):

You are displaying products in your cart, so I think you still need the array wrap the product.

So you need to map it and put the key-value in your product.

```php
$buy_number = array('buynumber' => $buynumber);
$product_array = $product->toArray();

array_map(function($product) use($buy_number) {
   return array_merge($product, $buy_number);}, 
$product_array);
```

Comment: I use this code
` $buy_number = array('buynumber' => $buynumber);`
  $product_array = $product->toArray();
   array_map(function($product,$buy_number) {
            return array_merge($product, $buy_number);}, 
         $product_array);`

I got error
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Customer\CustomerController::App\Http\Controllers\Customer\{closure}(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: @Daniel0909 I have updated it, you can try it again.

Comment: It is work. I add `$product_array['buynumber'] = $buynumber;`
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$product_array["buynumber"] = $buynumber;
```

If it still is a collection:

```
$product_array->buynumber = $buynumber;
```